# Unable to send 'version' message correctly

Tags: protocol, network, python

Few days ago I've found this [article](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html) about using raw Bitcoin protocol and now I'm trying to make my own transaction with Python. But I'm already stuck on sending `version` message.

I've tried to use [code snippets](https://github.com/shirriff/bitcoin-code) from the article. According to it, this code below should work, but Wireshark can't recognize anything and there's no `verack` response

```
import msgUtils
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("NODE_IP_ADDRESS", 8333)) # Shodan search 'port:8333'

sock.send(msgUtils.getVersionMsg())
sock.recv(1000) # receive version
sock.recv(1000) # receive verack
```

Maybe it don't work because article was written in 2014 and now it's totally outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, probably there is a mistake, here's a working version, which is based on this [code](https://github.com/Shultzi/Mybitcoin/blob/master/connection.py):

```
import time
import socket
import struct
import random

def makeMessage(cmd, payload):
    magic = "F9BEB4D9".decode("hex") # Main network
    command = cmd + (12 - len(cmd)) * "\00"
    length = struct.pack("I", len(payload))
    check = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(payload).digest()).digest()[:4]
    return magic + command + length + check + payload


def versionMessage():
    version = struct.pack("i", 60002)
    services = struct.pack("Q", 0)
    timestamp = struct.pack("q", time.time())
    addr_recv = struct.pack("Q", 0)
    addr_recv += struct.pack(">16s", "127.0.0.1")
    addr_recv += struct.pack(">H", 8333)
    addr_from = struct.pack("Q", 0)
    addr_from += struct.pack(">16s", "127.0.0.1")
    addr_from += struct.pack(">H", 8333)
    nonce = struct.pack("Q", random.getrandbits(64))
    user_agent_bytes = struct.pack("B", 0)
    height = struct.pack("i", 0)
    payload = version + services + timestamp + addr_recv + addr_from + nonce +user_agent_bytes + height
    return payload

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect(("93.170.187.9", 8333))
    sock.send(makeMessage("version", versionMessage()))
    sock.recv(1024) # version
    sock.recv(1024) # verack
```

Answer (score 1):

The msgUtils.py code didn't work with 64-bit Python due to a bug. I've fixed it, so you can try the updated code. (I'm the author of the article.)